# What is the purpose of withMiddlewareAuthRequired in the @auth0/nextjs-auth0 library?

Tags: next.js, auth0

**The problem I wanted to solve**: I have a GraphQL API and I need to authenticate the user inside it. I figured that the accessToken provided by the auth0 library could be used as a token. After reading the docs and trying different approaches, the only one that gave me any readable response was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75100784/18540403). Here, we are wrapping a middleware with the `withMiddlewareAuthRequired` function and calling `getSession` to store session details in the variable `user`.

Here's the code I used in my `middleware.js` file. It gives me the session details correctly.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import {
  withMiddlewareAuthRequired,
  getSession,
} from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/edge";

export default withMiddlewareAuthRequired(async function middleware(req) {
  const res = NextResponse.next();
  const user = await getSession(req, res);
  if (user) {
    console.log("session details: ", user);
    res.user = user;
    return user;
  }
  return res;
});
```

However, I wanted to modify this approach by setting up a route in `app/api/session` in which I can call `getSession`. This way I could simply call `fetch(/api/session)` and not have to use middleware.

Here's what I tried:

```
import { getSession } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req) {
  try {
    const res = new NextResponse();
    const user = await getSession(req, res);
    console.log("user: ", user);
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("session error: ", error);
  }
}
```

The `user` variable holds `null` value after this API call. Don't mind the fact that I'm not doing anything with it, what I'm concerned about is that it's `null`. Any insights?